# Flutter UI List Item

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the below code but not able to achieve the desired result, I am new to the flutter world so let me know where to improve to get the desired result. Here is the source code of what I have done.

```
return Expanded(
        child: GridView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemCount: albumList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return buildRow(index);
          },
        ),
      );


  Widget buildRow(int index) {
    return AlbumTile(
      index: index,
      albumList: albumList,
      deleteAlbum: _deleteAlbum,
    );
  }
```

This the Album Tile

```
class AlbumTile extends StatelessWidget {

  AlbumTile(
      {Key key,
      @required this.index,
      @required this.albumList,
      @required this.deleteAlbum})
      : super(key: key);

  final int index;
  final List<Album> albumList;
  final Function deleteAlbum;

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    String thumb;

    if (albumList.elementAt(index).thumbUrl != "") {
      thumb = WEBSERVICE_IMAGES +
          albumList.elementAt(index).userId.toString() +
          '/' +
          albumList.elementAt(index).id.toString() +
          '/' +
          albumList.elementAt(index).thumbUrl;
    } else {
      thumb = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg";
    }

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                new AlbumPage(tabIndex: index, albumList: albumList),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        // height of the card which contains full item
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.28,
        // this is the background image code
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                // url is my own public image url
                image: NetworkImage(thumb),
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
        // this is the item which is at the bottom
        child: Align(
          // aligment is required for this
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          // items height should be there, else it will take whole height
          // of the parent container
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 0.0),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      // Text() using hard coded text right now
                      Text(albumList.elementAt(index).name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.5,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                      SizedBox(height: 3.0),
                      Text(albumList.elementAt(index).photos.toString() +' photos',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12.5,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                // pop-up item
                PopupMenuButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.white),
                  itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
                    new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.delete),
                          Text(
                            'Delete Album',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      value: 'Delete',
                    ),
                  ],
                  onSelected: (value) {
                    deleteAlbum(albumList.elementAt(index).id, index);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                new AlbumPage(tabIndex: index, albumList: albumList),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.loose,
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                height: 1000,
                placeholder: kPlaceHolderImage,
                image: thumb,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        albumList.elementAt(index).name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18.5,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  PopupMenuButton(
                      icon: ImageIcon(
                        AssetImage("graphics/horizontal_dots.png"),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
                            new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  Text(
                                    'Delete Album',
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              value: 'Delete',
                            ),
                          ],
                      onSelected: (value) {
                        deleteAlbum(albumList.elementAt(index).id, index);
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: there are few things you need to add to your code to achieve the result....

Comment: For you to get the number of photo widget you can either wrap it with  Column or use RichText

Comment: the three dotted icon is called more_vert
https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=more_vert&style=baseline

Comment: on the click of the more vertical button you will bring up the popupmenu dialog.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the flutter. Amazing platform to start you career on `building cross-platform mobile applications`.

My code will look a bit different to you, but trust me, this will work out for you.

**Please note:** You need to change some parts, like changing the `image url` for `NetworkImage()`, `onTap` function, `Text()` content **etc**. But not much changes in the Whole Widget code. So please look for those, and make changes accordingly. You will get there :)

```
       GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print('Works!'), // <-- onTap change, I have used print()
          child: Container(
             // height of the card which contains full item
             height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4, 
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.28,
             // this is the background image code
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
               image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                // url is my own public image url
                image: NetworkImage('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg')
               ),
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)
            ),
            // this is the item which is at the bottom
            child: Align(
              // aligment is required for this
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              // items height should be there, else it will take whole height
              // of the parent container
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 0.0),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          // Text() using hard coded text right now
                          Text('Potraits', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          SizedBox(height: 3.0),
                          Text('150 photos', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                        ]
                      )
                    ),
                    
                    // pop-up item
                    PopupMenuButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.white),
                      itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
                        new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.delete),
                              Text(
                                'Delete Album',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          value: 'Delete',
                        ),
                      ],
                      onSelected: (value) {
                        //your function
                      }
                    )
                  ]
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
```

**Result**

[image: Result Capture]

**EDITS FOR WHOLE UI**

So, the change required is in your `buildRow` Widget. You just need to give some paddings on your sides, and you are pretty much solid. Let me know

```
  Widget buildRow(int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: AlbumTile(
        index: index,
        albumList: albumList,
        deleteAlbum: _deleteAlbum,
      )
    );
  }
```

And if you are unsatisfied with the spacings, just keep playing with the [EdgeInsets painting class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets-class.html). I hope that helps. Please let me know. :)

Comment: How come @KanwarpreetSingh The output is the result of the code. Share your code if you have gotten any help from this code, and also the problem you are facing here in your question. Make edits :) Let us look at the problem and solve it

Comment: Great @KanwarpreetSingh Waiting for that! Let me know :)

Comment: Done. Kindly check the current code and the screenshot.

Comment: See @KanwarpreetSingh It is coming up fine. **You were concerned about the Widget's UI, not the whole UI. Hence you just pointed out the card code. And I have made the changes in the card code only**. Now it about whole Page UI with those cards. Those two things are dfiferent Kanwar. I am going to do that for you now. Please wait for a while :)

Comment: Wait I will provide you the code for the GrieView as well.

Comment: Yes, I need the `GridView` code, cos the `CardView` is fine. @KanwarpreetSingh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219584/discussion-between-kanwarpreet-singh-and-alok).